# simultaneously toggle/slide DIV's

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggle

I have two divs:

```
     #main_body_div and .right-sidebar

     #main_body_div {
        margin:158px 0 0 150px;
        padding:0 10px 40px 0;
        background:#fff;
        min-height:100%;
        height:auto;
        width: auto;
        overflow: auto;
     }

     .right-sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 158px;
        bottom: 30px;
        right: 0;
        width: 235px;
        padding: 15px 20px 15px 15px;
        background: #f5f5f5;
     }
```

I try to make the right sidebar toggle to and fro with this:

```
     $('.menu-link').click(function() {
        if($('#main_body_div').hasClass('open'))
        {
            $('#main_body_div').removeClass('open');
            $('#main_body_div').css('width', '-=235px');
            $('.right-sidebar').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        }
        else
        {
            $('#main_body_div').addClass('open');
            $('#main_body_div').css('width', '+=235px');
            $('.right-sidebar').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        }
    });
```

unfortunately it doesn't work completly fault free..

What I would like it to do is slide open the right-sidebar - and at the same time adjust main_body_div to the right-sidebar space (and viceversa on closing sidebar)

It is not difficult to make right sidebar toggle on overlay of main body..

Anyone?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dG4Ks/

Comment: Meaning you want to push the the main content when the right side bar comes out?

Comment: Yes. adjust main content when toggling side bar.
Latest jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dG4Ks/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is ok for you.I have created a main content div and right floated menu when expands pushes the main content
html

```
    <div id = "page">
   <div id = "sidebar_right"class = "div_prop"></div><!--
   --><div id = "content" class = "div_prop">
    <div id = "menu_icon">&#9776;</div>
    <h1>Main Content</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
  html,body,#page{
    width:auto;
    background:silver;
    height:100%;
}
.div_prop{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    height:100%;
}
#content{
    background:grey;
    width:90%;
    color:white;

}
#sidebar_right{
    background:tomato;
    width:10%;
    display:none;
   -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
}
#menu_icon{
    font-size:20px;
    color:tomato;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    float:right;
}
.showmenu{
    display:inline-block!important;
}
.changeback{
    background:grey!important;
}
```

jquery

```
$("#menu_icon").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("changeback");
   $("#sidebar_right").toggleClass("showmenu");

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/fK3vC/5/)

Comment: Seems to do the trick (http://jsfiddle.net/fK3vC/8/) Will test it in application later.

Comment: Tested.. And yes.. worked perfect (had to add a .page-with-sidebar #main_body_div)